# Net Asset Value for Shares in Startup

Tags: accounting, stock-valuation

Assume a situation where an employee of a privately-held startup exercises a share option and receives 1 share and decides to leave. Per the option agreement the company has an 'option' to purchase all shares held by that employee at the **Net Asset Value per share**.

Other basic facts about Company X:

- Company X is a technology startup that just received $1m cash from a VC based on a $5m valuation. This is due to the unique software it sells to customers.
- Company X only holds the cash as an asset on the balance sheet and has no liabilities.
- Company X recently had a non-binding offer to sell for $7m.

If the company decides to exercise the buyback option how will the 'net asset value' be calculated?

Comment: Any agreement that refers to something like 'Net Asset Value per share' should have definitions for these terms - and if they don't, then jurisdictional norms would likely prevail; typically speaking as someone seeing that term the way you've presented it, I would expect that the calculation of NAV should align with the system of accounting used by the company [likely referred to in that agreement - either US GAAP or IFRS or whatever].

Answer (score 1):

If the company has $1 million in assets (it would be odd to take money from a VC just to hold it on the books) and $0 in liabilities, the net asset value of the company is $1 million.  The net asset value of the shares would be $1 million divided by the number of shares outstanding.

Comment: Thanks Justin! So there is no consideration of 'intangibles' or fair market value when calculating net asset value? What definition is generally accepted in these matters, for example, is GAAP/IFRS relevant?